# Confusion with merging in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, github-pages

So I have a project that has two branches, the master and gh-pages.  I am doing all my work on my master branch and want to put those changes onto the gh-pages branch.  I am quite confused on how to do that through Visual Studio 2017, as well as the differences between merging from master into the gh-pages and merging from gh-pages into master.  I know some people have it so that gh-pages will be 'somewhat automatically' updated everytime changes are made in master, but all I want to do is update my gh-pages branch with changes from master when I need to.  Can someone explain to me how to do so through Visual Studio?

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge of git commands and workflow.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the attached link from Microsoft

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenakamu/2017/10/01/git-and-visual-studio-2017-part-5/

Take a look at the Merge in VS section. 
Hopefully this should provide enough of a guide for you to perform the requested action.

Here's a quick snippet from the page that specifically shows the steps on merging branches. You'll need to just change the branches that are being referenced to the ones that you're using -

2. Go to Team Explorer and select Branches. Checkout master and click “Merge”. Same as Git command, you need to be on master to merge dev branch.
3. Select dev on “Merge from branch” menu and click Merge. Note that I keep “Commit changes after merging” checkbox on.

Comment: please include the essential parts of the link content in your answer, if the link breaks your answer will be useless for the future readers

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, open the Team Explorer view. At the top there's a drop down where you can click 'Branches'. After clicking that you will see your master and gh-pages branch. Make sure you're on the branch you want to merge into i.e. 'gh-pages' and then right click the 'master' branch. A context menu will appear with 'merge from' option. Click that and then click 'merge'. That's one way to merge, the branching strategy you should use is a different question altogether.